# php destroy a session which is not the current session

Tags: php, session

If a user opens a session, I would like to destroy all other sessions that he might have.

I know `session_destroy();` but it destroys only the current session.

How can I do to destroy another session? (I know the other session id)

Comment: How do you know which sessions he owns?

Comment: Let's assume I know the session_id of ther other sessions.

Comment: What session do you want do destory? Do you have its id or you want to destroy all the other sessions?

Comment: If you have its ID, I suggest you the workaround Trott mentioned

Comment: Thank you, that's what I will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the session id for the session you want to destroy, you can pass it to `session_start()` to resume that session, destroy it, then call `session_start()` again to create the new session.  I haven't tried this to confirm it will work, but it seems like it ought to.

If you do not have the session id for the session you want to destroy, I'm not sure there's a sane, clean, portable way to do this.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As long as sessions contain a value that identifies the user it belongs to, this is technically possible.

For example, you can store sessions in a database, and then destroy all sessions but the current active one by deleting all other sessions from the database.

You wrote in your question you know already the other session id you want to destroy (`$sessionIDDelte`):

```
$backup = session_id($sessionIDDelte);
session_start(); # load session data
$_SESSION = array(); # do not use unset();
session_destroy(); # close and remove session

session_id($backup); # switch to current session
session_start();
```

This works independent to the session store. If you're using the file-system, you could just unlink the file with the session id you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default session handler before calling session_start():

```
session_set_save_handler(new \SessionHandler());
```

Then, destroy the session with the ID stored in $sessionID:

```
(new \SessionHandler())->destroy($sessionID);
```